# X509 certificate that can only be installed on a particular machine

Tags: certificate, authentication, x509

Is it possible to create a certificate that will not install on a machine other than its intended one? (Using some hardware fingerprint embedded into the cert?)

Or alternatively, is there a way to detect from the receiving side of a TLS connection that the certificate is coming from the wrong machine (other than just keeping a lookup table of IPs)

The goal is to authenticate using the certificate, and ensure that the certificate has not been shared or given away.

Comment: How do you define "a particular machine"? What unique machine identifier are you hoping to tie the cert to? It might also help if you specify what platform(s) you care about, because the answer for, say, a Windows 8.1 PC might be different from, say, an iPad.

Comment: Windows or Linux in general. Open to many types of fingerprinting, something other than the default "install-able anywhere". hardware mac address, cpu ID, hard drive ID etc. 

Its not really a big deal if they need to be re-generated if the fingerprint changes, but just a way to validate that the cert is not being freely distributed to share access.

Comment: Do you need this to be "perfectly" secure, or would you be open to a solution that makes exporting/sharing private keys, while not impossible, still a technical PITA that most not-highly-technical users won't bother with?

Comment: The second should be good enough.